# Generate HTML code coverage reports with intern

Tags: intern, istanbul

The [intern](/questions/tagged/intern) testing framework (http://theintern.io) comes with built in [istanbul](/questions/tagged/istanbul) support.

Adding `lcov` to the reports array generates only a lcov.info file which might be converted with `genhtml`:

```
define({
  // ..
  reporters: [
    'lcov'
  ],
  //..
});
```

Is it possible to generate a full html report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'lcovhtml' (Intern 1.4–2.2) or 'LcovHtml' (Intern 3+) reporter to generate a full HTML coverage report.